# Network pushnotification

Tags: android, ios, networking, web-applications, push-notification

I want to make a party next week and would like to play a game with my guests.
I found a card game in which you get a challenge you have to do and get a new challenge card if you do this successful.

I wonder if it is possible to tell everyone to connect to my wifi (android and iphone) and then everyone get pushnotifications with the challenge they have to do and mark them as successful.

Is this somehow possible to realize this with a webapp?

Comment: for achieving this firstly do network discovery if device is connected to wi-fi then save device on your sever and send notification to all device connected to same IP address.

Answer (score 0):

To send Push Notifications it is necessary that you have your native apps installed on the devices.